# Resizing a Panels based on the size of user control

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, devexpress

I'm trying to find a way to resize a LayoutPanel (DevExpress) based on the size of the user control that it contains. The user control is exposed using a ContentControl. Here's the relevant Code
This is the Layout panel and the coresponding view:

```
<dxd:LayoutPanel Caption="Search Criteria" CaptionImage="Images/Icons/DetailView.png">
   <ContentControl Name="myContentControl" Content="{Binding Path=ProjectsSearchVM}"/>
 </dxd:LayoutPanel>
```

The ProjectSearchVM is a property of the MainWindowViewModel, which is the DataContext for the code above. This property returns an object of type ProjectsSearchViewModel that is replaced by its corresponding View (containing a userControl) using a Resource File:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ProjectSearchViewModel}">
  <vw:ProjectSearchView />
</DataTemplate>
```

The problem is that my view is higher than the original size of the Layout Pannel. I'd like to bind the panel's MinSize to the size of my view (or the ContentControl containing it).

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<dxd:LayoutPanel Caption="Search Criteria" CaptionImage="Images/Icons/DetailView.png">
  <dxd:LayoutPanel.MinSize>
    <Binding ElementName="myContentControl" Path="Size"/>
  </dxd:LayoutPanel.MinSize>


   <ContentControl Name="myContentControl" Content="{Binding Path=ProjectsSearchVM}" />
</dxd:LayoutPanel>
```

I'm still very new to WPF, so I'm sure the solution is simple.
Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: I have precisely the same question.

Comment: try reflecting the DevExpress assembly and look at the MeasureOverride virtual method on the LayoutPanel. If it supports auto there will be a check for Height/width == Double.NaN somewhere in that method.

Comment: If you would ask the reverse. It's easy. These container objects(Grid,Stackpanel has Children property). Each children register an event while adding and deregister while removig///. But In your question you need such as OnChildrenAddEvent which not exist. So try to handle your template changes. You may try registering UpdateLayout event. And do things with Layout's.Childeren.Max(Width) then set it to LayoutRoot. Its a bit hack y but  may solve your issue.

Comment: did you try to bind MaxWidth and MinHeight instead of Size?

Answer (score 0):

The question was answered on the DevExpress site at this link:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q448884

For flyout, it involves overriding the control in the container, for example, if it's in a `Border`, something like this:

```
public class AutoSizeContainer : Border {
        protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e) {
            base.OnInitialized(e);
            BaseLayoutItem item = DockLayoutManager.GetLayoutItem(this);
            Child.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
            AutoHideGroup.SetAutoHideSize(item, new Size(Child.DesiredSize.Width + 6, Child.DesiredSize.Height + 6));
        }
    }
```

Making such an object the root object of the `LayoutPanel` in an `AutoHide` group, makes the flyout sizing correct.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with DevExpress's LayoutPanel, but most standard WPF panels (Grid, StackPanel) "auto size" to contain their children. Are you setting hard Height and Width properties for the LayoutPanel (or does it only contain a Size property and not Height and Width like standard WPF controls)?

If you are forced to use hard Height/Width values, a common way to bind them would be like this:

```
<dxd:LayoutPanel ... Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=myContentControl}" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=myContentControl}">
   <ContentControl x:Name=myContentControl ... />
</dxd:LayoutPanel>
```

Normally, if you bind Heights and Widths you bind to ActualHeight or ActualWidth, but those properties do not exist on ContentControl. (Height and Width are only suggested values, so you may find that if the above binding is needed and works for you, you may need to tweak the values slightly with a value converter to account for margins or padding).

Comment: Question is specific to a known condition in DevExpress' Layout controls